# i want to delete my group in Facebook but i can not?

Tags: facebook

i have a group in Facebook with 14000 users, now i want to delete this group but Facebook does not allow delete it without deleting users! now you think what will happen if i delete all 14000 users!
is there any way to delete group without deleting user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the script found here: https://gist.github.com/adriaanm/1962608.

Just paste this javascript in your browser address bar when you are at the page https://www.facebook.com/groups/GROUP_TO_DELETE/members/

```
deleteAll = [];
deleteAll.elms = [];

deleteAll.canClick = function (el) {
  return (typeof el != 'undefined') && (typeof el.click != 'undefined');
}

deleteAll.load = function() {
  deleteAll.elms = document.getElementsByClassName("mhm auxiliaryButton closeButton uiCloseButton");
  if (deleteAll.elms.length < 5 ) {
    setTimeout(deleteAll.getMore, 1000);
  } else {
    setTimeout(deleteAll.go, 2000);
  }
}

deleteAll.getMore = function() {
  more = document.getElementsByClassName("pam uiBoxLightblue  uiMorePagerPrimary");
  if (typeof more != 'undefined' && deleteAll.canClick(more[0])) { 
    more[0].click();
    setTimeout(deleteAll.load, 2000);
  } else {
    setTimeout(deleteAll.load, 100);
  }
}

deleteAll.go = function() {
  try {
    deleteAll.doClick(2);
  } catch(e) {
    setTimeout(deleteAll.load, 1000);
  } finally {
    setTimeout(deleteAll.load, 500000);
  }
}

deleteAll.doClick = function(i) {
  deleteAll.elms[i].click();
  setTimeout(function(){deleteAll.confirm(i + 1)}, 750);
}

deleteAll.confirm = function (i) {
  remove_but = document.getElementsByName("confirm")[0];

  if (i < deleteAll.elms.length - 5 && deleteAll.canClick(remove_but) && remove_but.value == "Confirm") {
    remove_but.click();
    setTimeout(function(){deleteAll.doClick(i)}, 500);
  } else {
    setTimeout(deleteAll.getMore, 2000);
  }
}

// deleteAll.fullRestart = function() {
//   membersLink = document.getElementsByClassName("groupsCleanLink groupsCleanLinksSelected");
//   if (typeof membersLink != 'undefined' && deleteAll.canClick(membersLink[0])) { membersLink[0].click(); }
//   setTimeout(deleteAll.go, 5000);
// }

deleteAll.load();
```

Comment: have you tried it in new Facebook UI? just see the comments in that link that you referred please. thank you

Comment: Nope, tested it with my Facebook (still old UI) and a test group.

Comment: look i opened that link(xxxx/members/) and i pasted it in console(pressed F12 and in console pasted that code) but i got 'undefined' where is my mistake ?

Comment: Probably the script isn't up to date anymore, like the commands on the github suggest. I can't test it on my own Facebook so I don't know what's wrong...